# Angular 2: Child Routes not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am learning Angular 2 and get stuck at setting up the child routes.

I am trying to build the simple ToDo app and couldn't manage to set up the route for adding a new item.

That's what I am trying to get and 'todo/add' link is not working and keep giving me 404 error.

Examples:

- localhost/todo
- localhost/todo/add

I added todo.module.ts in app.module.ts.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./not-found.component";
import { TodoListComponent } from "./todo/todo-list.component";

import { TodoModule } from "./todo/todo.module";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'todo', component: TodoListComponent },
            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
        ],
            TodoModule)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        TodoListComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And set up the child routes in todo.module.ts for todo/add

todo.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TodoListComponent } from './todo-list.component';
import { TodoAddComponent } from './todo-add.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: 'todo', component: TodoListComponent },
            { path: 'todo/add', component: TodoAddComponent }
            // tested these routes and not working too
            //{ path: 'add', component: TodoAddComponent }
            //{ path: 'todo/:id', component: TodoAddComponent }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        TodoAddComponent,
        TodoListComponent
    ],
    providers: [

    ]
})
export class TodoModule { }
```

I tested 3 possible ways which I found on the Internet and all of them give me 404 error (which redirects to PageNotFoundComponent)

```
<h1>Todo List</h1>
<a [routerLink]="['/todo/add']">Add New Item with /</a><br />
<a [routerLink]="['/todo', 'add']">Add New Item</a><br />
<a [routerLink]="['add']">Add New Item</a>
```

They rendered as /todo/add, /todo/add, /add but all of them are hitting 404 error.

[image]

Could you guys please help me to sort out this problem?

Sometimes, I am very frustrated at myself (or probably Angular2) and couldn't understand why it's very difficult to learn/do just simple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All of them give me 404 error (which redirects to PageNotFoundComponent)

With your configuration, you'll never get an actual 404 from the server since the `**` path catches all paths that haven't been previously matched. The `**` "trick" is NOT an actual 404.

I think your problem is just that you match the `**` path **before** matching the paths declared in `TodoModule`.

If you look at the entire list of paths for your app, you have (in this order):

- `home` - from `AppModule`
- `todo` - from `AppModule`
- `**` - from `AppModule`
- `todo` - from `TodoModule` (why declare it twice??)
- `todo/add` - from `TodoModule`

The `**` path should come LAST. Try importing `TodoModule` **before** declaring the routes for `AppModule`:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // First, TodoModule and its routes
        TodoModule,
        // Then, the other routes including the **
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
        ])
    ]
})
```

(Also, if you copied your actual code, you imported `TodoModule` in the wrong place: it should be a member of the `imports` array; you placed it inside the `RouterModule.forRoot()` call.)

Comment: You saved me.  Thanks very much.  The main problem is I accidentally added TodoModule in ForRoot bracket.  Your explanation gave me clear view of how Routing in Angular2 works.

Comment: Additional question... if I type 'localhost/todo' or 'localhost/home' directly in a n address bar, it works... but if I type 'localhost/todo/add', it couldn't load all libraries.js files (shin.min, zone, reflect, etc) and giving me 404 for all of those libraries.

Comment: What code are you using to load the libraries? Are you using SystemJS or Webpack?

Comment: I am using SystemJS.

Comment: What code are you using to load the libraries? Is the official quickstart?

Comment: It's not official one.  I tweaked it to work in Visual Studio 2015, since I come from c# ASP.Net Platform.  I will post as a question when I got home.  Thanks.

Comment: I managed to make child route works with HashTag.  "{ useHash: true }" in Routes.forRoot.... Do I have to use it or is it just an optional?  If it is optional, obviously, I am doing wrong something in configurations.  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds strange. Sorry but I don't see what the problem is.